# jQuery Mobile Site's Aspect Ratio Changed After Site Transfer

Tags: jquery, mobile, dimensions, aspect-ratio

I have two identical sites, in terms of code, sitting on two different servers. One is in my server's test environment and the other is on the client's server.

After transferring the site, however, the aspect ratio changed on the client's version of the mobile site.

Any reason this may be happening? An issue with the server?

I'm at a loss as to why identical code could be causing changes in the aspect ratio/dimensions displayed on a mobile device. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the root cause of the issue was the client was using a URL-masking forwarding method to point to a sub-domain.

For example, consider if the client were to already have a domain/website at:

www.webuyboats.com

And they wanted to host all of the files encompassing an entirely different website that you designed for them on a subdomain, such as:

collegeadvice.webuyboats.com

But they purchased the domain:

www.collegeadvice.com

And when people navigate to the above domain it just "points" the browser to the files hosted at the subdomain with a URL-masking, it distorts the aspect ratio used by jQuery mobile. In order to correct this, the files need to co-exist with the domain or URL-masking needs to be turned off.